# Is Okta OIDC documentation outdated?

Tags: openid-connect, okta

According to [Okta Docs](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oidc.html#get-keys) a JSON response document containing a `x5c` key is expected on `/oauth2/v1/keys` endpoint, but there's no such key.  Was this endpoint updated and documentation got outdated?

Example on [GitHub](https://github.com/jpf/okta-oidc-beta/issues/4)

Comment: Documentation has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Sent a ticket to Okta Support and they thanked me and confirmed that indeed documentation is outdated and they no longer expose the x5c.
For my purpose that key was not required, but documentation remains outdated.